# How to resolve error 400 with method POST of Django Rest Framework when I create join method

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

I am redoing a course on DRF and I am trying to post a user and a group as the request's body. The request is supposed to trigger the join method, but I get error 400 and the user does not become a part of the group, what should I do?

The views, the models, and the serializers are below.

views.py

```
class MemberViewSet(ModelViewSet):
        queryset = Member.objects.all()
        serializer_class = MemberSerializer    
        
        @action(detail=False, methods=['post'])
        def join(self, request):
            if 'group' in request.data and 'user' in request.data:
                try:
                    group = Group.objects.get(id=request.data['group'])
                    user = User.objects.get(id=request.data['user'])
                    member = Member.objects.create(user=user, group=group, admin=False)
                    serializer = MemberSerializer(member, many=False)
                    response = {'message': 'Joined group', 'results': serializer.data}
    
                    return Response(response, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
                except:
                    response = {'message': 'Cannot join'}
                    return Response(response, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
            else:
                response = {'message': 'Wrong params'}
                return Response(response, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

models.py

```
        from django.db import models, transaction
        from django.contrib.auth.models import User
        
        # Create your models here.
        class Group(models.Model):
            name = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=False, unique=False)
            location = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=False)
            description = models.CharField(max_length=250, null=False, unique=False)
            active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
            class Meta:
                unique_together=(('name', 'location'))
        
            def __str__(self):
                return self.name
       
            @transaction.atomic
            def disable(self):
                if self.active is False:
                    return
                self.active = False
                self.save()
                self.events.update(active=False)
            
        class Member(models.Model):
           
            group = models.ForeignKey(Group, related_name='members', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
            user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='members_of', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
            admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    
            class Meta:
                    unique_together = (('user', 'group'))
                    index_together = (('user', 'group'))
            
                def __str__(self):
                    return str(self.user)
```

serializers.py

```
        from django.contrib.auth.models import User
        from rest_framework.serializers import ModelSerializer
        from rest_framework import serializers
        from .models import Group, Member

        class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
            class Meta:
                model=User
                fields=('id', 'username')
   
        class MemberSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
            user = UserSerializer(many=False)
            class Meta:
                model=Member
                fields=('user', 'group', 'admin')

        class GroupSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
            events = EventSerializer(many=True)

            class Meta:
                model=Group
                fields='__all__'

        class GroupListSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
            class Meta:
                model=Group
                fields='__all__'

        class GroupDetailSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
            events = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
            members = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
            class Meta:
                model=Group
                fields=['name', 'location', 'description', 'active', 'members']
        
            def get_members(self, obj):
                people_points = []
                #queryset = instance.members.all()
                members = obj.members.all()
                for member in members:
                    points = 0
                    member_serialized = MemberSerializer(member, many=False)
                    member_data = member_serialized.data
                    member_data['point'] = points
                    people_points.append(member_data)
                return people_points
```

Comment: Can you please post the body of the request....

Comment: @Mau I added it's cropped by stackOVF. class MemberViewSet(ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Member.objects.all()
    serializer_class = MemberSerializer
  before section code above